# Настройка VPN в Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vps

Подскажите пожалуйста как или с помощью какой программы я могу настроить VPN подключения с такими параметрами на Ubuntu.

скрин из программы softether vpn for windows
[image]

Comment: Просто скачайте softether vpn для linux (даже несколько ppa есть)

Comment: ...хотя, похоже, в линуксе у него нет графического интерфейса. Плохи дела

Comment: ...но в линуксе можно запустить виндовый интерфейс через вайн. Странные дела)

Comment: да я знаю что там есть linux версия но я её настоять не  могу еже 5 день. А через Wine она не работает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым правильным решением будет скачать Softether VPN для linux.
[Ссылка тут](https://www.softether-download.com/en.aspx?product=softether)